# ¿Por qué "venga" llegó a convertirse en una interjección en España?

Tags: modismos, españa

**¡Venga!** es una de las muletillas más típicas de los españoles, junto con *¡Vale!*

Literalmente es el presente del subjuntivo de *venir*. Hay frases en las que casi se entiende, como en

> -¿Quieres café?
> -Venga.

donde puedo imaginar que el café *va a venir*.

Pero generalmente no tiene nada que ver con eso. Por ejemplo:

> Venga, que has llegao temprano.
>
> -Gracias
> -Venga.
>
> Bueno, venga, hagámoslo como tú dices.

¿Deriva realmente "¡venga!" de "venir"? ¿Cómo evolucionó así?

Comment: En Argentina recientemente se ha extendido la muletilla "Dale!" con el mismo uso.

Comment: [Este anuncio de TV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bL1ATy9gV8&t=18s) de finales de los 80 o principios de los 90, protagonizado por el premio Nobel de literatura Camilo José Cela, popularizó enormemente el uso de *¡venga!* en España.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echando un vistazo al CORDE encuentro un par de casos en los que podríamos estar ante el antecesor del "venga" como muletilla sin significado. Son los siguientes:

> *[...] la oradora abrió la mano izquierda, haciendo ademán de escribir en ella con una tagarnina–: "Decreto yo, el pueblo soberano, en uso de mis derechos individuales, que todos los generales, gobernadores, ministros y gente gorda salgan del sitio que ocupan y se lo dejen a otros que nombraré yo del modo que me dé la realísima gana. He dicho."
>
>        –¡Bien, bien!
>
>        –¡Venga de ahí!*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, "La Tribuna", 1883 (España)
>
> ---
>
> *–Entonces... ¡venga otro trago! –exclamó el molinero, sentándose.
>
>        –¡Venga de ahí! –repuso el alcalde, alargándole el vaso lleno.*
>
> Pedro Antonio de Alarcón, "El sombrero de tres picos", 1874 (España)

En este último caso podemos ver que el primer "venga [otro trago]" equivaldría al primer ejemplo del café que pusiste, pero la respuesta "venga [de ahí]" equivaldría más bien al "venga" como "vale, de acuerdo".

De hecho, yo mismo he usado expresión como "venga ahí" usada para dar ánimos. Es muy probable que esta sea la expresión que se acortara y originara el actual "¡venga!" como interjección.

Te pongo un ejemplo más, en el que aparece "venga de ahí" con el sentido de "vale, adelante":

> *–[...] Voy a contarle a usted una cosa muy curiosa que me ocurrió hace poco.
>
>        Afiné mis cinco sentidos ante las palabras de este hombre, cuya naturalidad en el trato demostraba bien a las claras la certeza de sus explicaciones.
>
>        –Venga de ahí –contesté yo, deseoso de oírle.*
>
> Julio Escobar, "Itinerarios por las cocinas y las bodegas de Castilla", 1965 (España)

Una buena pregunta ahora podría ser ¿a qué se refieren con "ahí"?

Answer (score 1):

Algunas de estas "muletillas" se forman de casualidad. Ya sabemos que incluso por definición, una [*muletilla* o *latiguillo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muletilla) llega a carecer o a perder su significado real debido a este exceso deuso o mal uso.

`Venga` (o ¡venga!, más bien) es tanto una interjección para dar ánimo o meter prisa

> Venga, corre, que llegamos tarde
>
> Venga, vamos, que tú puedes

Como una expresión de incredulidad

> ¿Que tú has sacado un diez en matemáticas?, ¡Venga ya! No me lo creo

El primer uso es equivalente a "Vamos" y yo entiendo que es la corrupción de este uso como interjección para meter prisa del que se origina la muletilla. El (mal) uso de "venga" en esos contextos es como decir "Pues venga/vamos, pasemos a lo siguiente" hasta llegar a ser (mal) usado como equivalente de "Vale. Entendido." por la conotación de "estoy de acuerdo".

> (por teléfono). Pues nos vemos mañana entonces. Adiós.
>
> vale. *venga*. (pues eso, adiós, colguemos el teléfono y cada uno a sus cosas)

o también

> - Venga (*vamos, presta atenció a esto que te voy a decir*), que has llegao temprano.
>
> -Gracias
>
> -Venga. (*pues vale*. En lugar de "de nada")

Para

> Bueno, **venga**, hagámoslo como tú dices.

lo veo menos como muletilla y mucho más como un equivalente de "vamos (a ello)", pero bien prodría ser un "vale".